# MongoDB Query Optimize Search Text

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, query-optimization

I have an application developed in NodeJS, which works as a REST API and consumes data from MongoDB

In MongoDB I have a collection called 'ftp' with more than 10 million documents with the following structure

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59e7c66911506bd1725cf145"),
        "ip" : "72.32.177.76",
        "timestamp" : "2017-10-16T02:30:26-04:00",
        "data" : {
                "banner" : "220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta\r\n"
        }       
}
```

The "data.banner" field is a hased index

From NoodeJs I make an aggregate query that filters a string of text using a regular expression, groups and counts the results.

```
function getData(timeInit, table, textSearch, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.collection(table).aggregate([
            {
                $match: { 'data.banner': $regex:textSearch}
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$data.banner',
                    num: { $sum: 1 },                   
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    num: -1
                }
            },{
                $limit:5
            }
        ], {
                allowDiskUse: true
            }
        ).toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var timeFinal = new Date();
            var data = {
                result: result,
                timeLapse: (timeFinal - timeInit) / 1000,
                numResult: result.length
            };
            res.send(data);
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

The query with regular expression takes about 8 seconds to return results, an excessive time in my opinion, since the regular expressions are not optimal.

My question is how should I make the filter to search for documents that contain text in an optimal way reducing the response time.

If someone knows how to optimize this type of query I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: What are some examples of `textSearch`? MongoDB cannot use indices with regex if you don't start them with the anchor `^`.

Comment: for example, text Search = "ftpd"

In what way do I use ^?

Comment: It has to be at the start of the regex, "starts with:" https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, I'll only search for text strings beginning with textSearch, but I need to search for all those containing textSearch

Comment: Right ... it may be difficult to optimize the query then. Does `data.banner` have an index?

Comment: yes "data.banner" has a hash index, if I look for equality the query is instantaneous, but when searching with regular expression it takes great time